# What encryption algorithm preserves file differences?

Tags: encryption, backup

I would like to encrypt a file with most secure algorithm that also meets the following requirement.

Let's say we have a text file that has 100 Bytes and we encrypt it.
Now we change 1 byte in original file and encrypt again.

If we make a diff of the encrypted files then ideal encryption algorithm should produce the shortest diff possible - e.g. 1 byte.

(Essentially I want to do a incremental backup of encrypted files and minimize bandwidth requirements)

Answer (score 1):

If you use [CTR (counter)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encryption_mode) mode, I believe you will get the result you require.

Comment: Or a stream cypher would give the same effect.  A block cypher in CTR mode is effectively a stream cypher.